# SUMO: Variable Dijkstra Routing Algorithm

Tags: routes, simulation, veins, sumo

SUMO provides four [routing algorithms](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/userdoc/Simulation/Routing.html#Routing_Algorithms) including Dijkstra. Does it uses variable Dijkstra to avoid congestion on new route? Means whenever a vehicle is rerouted, whole network is investigated again to find shortest / fastest path?

Comment: See http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Demand/Automatic_Routing and http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Rerouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SUMO can do fully dynamic rerouting. The first link given in the comment by Julian Heinovski basically answers this. This is not necessarily a question of the routing algorithm but rather whether a rerouting device is used. So only when using the device you will get the fully dynamic behavior.